Is there a method to validate in laravel backend that a newly drawn polygon with leaflet maps doesn't intersect with a previously saved polygon?
I am using leaflet maps to draw polygons , I save only one polygon each time , coordinates data are saved in mongodb , here is how one saved polygon data looks like in database:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66951c1f1d5ccea27f03cd28"
  },
  "id": 405,
  "type": "polygon",
  "coords": [
    [
      30.608626407820356,
      31.720967336485014
    ],
    [
      30.09193235135625,
      31.753944088506564
    ],
    [
      30.006344842807106,
      31.28677343486776
    ],
    [
      30.281861608344087,
      31.171354802792283
    ],
    [
      30.608626407820356,
      31.720967336485014
    ]
  ],
  "options": {
    "color": "#47dd3c"
  },
  "zone": {
    "code": "1",
    "name": "sddsa",
    "description": "sddas",
    "color": "#9a7474",
    "updated_at": "2024-07-15T12:54:55.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2024-07-15T12:54:55.000000Z",
    "id": 1
  },
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": "2024-07-15T13:15:30.700Z"
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": "2024-07-15T12:54:55.972Z"
  }
}

and here is how the polygon data are sent to backend:
"
[{"id":362,"type":"polygon","coords":[[29.744370137958683,30.967977436404976],[29.069636417803626,31.97926449839962],[28.78116333312449,30.88003943101416]],"options":{"stroke":true,"color":"#3388ff","weight":4,"opacity":0.5,"fill":true,"fillColor":null,"fillOpacity":0.2,"clickable":true}}]
 ◀
"

I use json_decode to be able to handle the data and manipulate it and save it to database.
Is there a method to validate that this polygon doesn't intersect with or contains or is contained in any previously saved polygon?
I tried making this function to validate polygon data after using json_decode() :
    public function validateGeoData($geoData, $currentZoneId = null)
    {
        $coords = $geoData->coords;
        if ($coords[0] !== end($coords)) {
            $coords[] = $coords[0];
        }

        // Ensure coordinates are properly formatted as arrays of arrays
        $formattedCoords = array_map(function ($coord) {
            return is_array($coord) ? $coord : [$coord];
        }, $coords);

        $geoJson = [
            'type' => 'Polygon',
            'coordinates' => [$formattedCoords]
        ];

        // Start with a base query for checking intersections
        $query = GEOZone::whereRaw([
            'coords' => [
                '$geoIntersects' => [
                    '$geometry' => $geoJson
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        // Exclude the current zone ID if provided (for update scenario)
        if ($currentZoneId) {
            $query->where('zone.id', '!=', $currentZoneId);
        }

        // Check for intersections
        $intersectingZones = $query->exists();

        if ($intersectingZones) {
            return __('Zone.this_zone_intersects_with_an_existing_zone');
        }

        // Additional custom validations can be added here if needed

        return null; // Return null if validation passes
    }

And I then add its return to validation errors and it works fine in case of the new polygon contains a previously existing polygon and in some cases of intersection. But in other cases of intersection and if new polygon is contained in a previously existing polygon, validation doesn't work and record is saved successfully.
